# Router error with laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm getting this error with laravel, does anyone know how to fix:

```
#1 {main} [] []
[2014-01-21 15:31:09] development.ERROR: exception 'Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception   \FatalErrorException' with message 'Call to undefined method Illuminate\Routing\Router::deleted()' in /vagrant/shop.net/private/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php:296
Stack trace:

#0 [internal function]: Illuminate\Exception\Handler->handleShutdown()
#1 {main} [] []
```

I've tried a composer update but does not appear to work.

Comment: have you updated your Laravel recently, or made other changes to your installation?  Is this a recently installed Laravel?

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` too?

Comment: Its been updated to 4.1, and was working fine until I did a composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 0):

Steps that usually fix Laravel, when the problem is not on your source code, of course:

```
cd /your/application/dir

rm bootstrap/compiled.php

rm -rf vendor

composer update --no-dev
```